# CUDA: Pass device function as an argument to global function

Tags: cuda

How to make something like this work?

```c
#define Eval(x, y, func) {y = func(x);}
__global__ void Evaluate(double *xs, double *ys, int N, double f(double))
{
    int tid = threadIdx.x;
    if (tid < N)
        Eval(xs[tid], ys[tid], f);
        
    
}
```

And then inside main function I have

```c
    double *xs_d, *ys_d;
    double *xs_h, *ys_h;
    xs_h = (double *) malloc(sizeof(double) * 256);
    ys_h = (double *) malloc(sizeof(double) * 256);
    cudaMalloc((void **)&xs_d, sizeof(double) * 256);
    cudaMalloc((void **)&ys_d, sizeof(double) * 256);
    for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
    {
        xs_h[i] = (double)i;
    }
    HANDLE_ERROR(cudaMemcpy(xs_d, xs_h, 256*sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
    Evaluate<<<1,256>>>(xs_d, ys_d, 256, Sin);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    HANDLE_ERROR(cudaMemcpy(ys_h, ys_d, 256*sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));
```

It fails in the last line. So far I have seen solutions like this [How to pass device function as an input argument to host-side function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18485990/how-to-pass-device-function-as-an-input-argument-to-host-side-function) but there they use `__device__` functions, which cannot be changed or accessed by a host (`main` for example) function. For example, I cannot put `__device__ int *fptrf1 = (int *)f1;` (taken from the example) inside main. Is it possible to somehow have this flexibility?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> For example, I cannot put `__device__ int *fptrf1 = (int *)f1;` (taken from the example) inside `main`. Is it possible to somehow have this flexibility?

One possible approach is to use a [lambda](https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/new-compiler-features-cuda-8/):

```
$ cat t151.cu
#define Eval(x, y, func) {y = func(x);}
template <typename F>
__global__ void Evaluate(double *xs, double *ys, int N, F f)
{
    int tid = threadIdx.x;
    if (tid < N)
        Eval(xs[tid], ys[tid], f);


}

int main(){
    double *xs_d, *ys_d;
    double *xs_h, *ys_h;
    xs_h = (double *) malloc(sizeof(double) * 256);
    ys_h = (double *) malloc(sizeof(double) * 256);
    cudaMalloc((void **)&xs_d, sizeof(double) * 256);
    cudaMalloc((void **)&ys_d, sizeof(double) * 256);
    for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
    {
        xs_h[i] = (double)i;
    }

    cudaMemcpy(xs_d, xs_h, 256*sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    auto Sinlambda = [] __host__ __device__ (double v) {return sin(v);};
    Evaluate<<<1,256>>>(xs_d, ys_d, 256, Sinlambda);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    cudaMemcpy(ys_h, ys_d, 256*sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
}
$ nvcc -o t151 t151.cu -std=c++11 --extended-lambda
$ cuda-memcheck ./t151
========= CUDA-MEMCHECK
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors
$
```

(CUDA 11.3)

For a variety of device function pointer uses, this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31057870/passing-host-function-as-a-function-pointer-in-global-or-device-function/31058123#31058123) links to a number of examples.

Comment: Thanks. I have a few follow-up questions. What does `__host__ __device__` mean? What does `[]` mean in `[] __host__ __device__` mean? Is this a pointer to the function? Instead of using the template, can I hard-code the type? What would the type be then?

Comment: `__host__ __device__` is used to declare to the CUDA compiler that you want this function callable from either host or device code.  The `__host__` portion is unnecessary for this example, you could delete that and it would work the same way.  `[ ]` syntax is part of the C++ lambda syntax.  I wouldn't be able to give you a tutorial on C++ lambda functions in the space of these comments.